# Got daDK error on netlify while building react + material ui x data grid project

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, netlify

The project is running successfully on the local machine in dev mode.
but got this error on netlify.

```
./node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/locales/daDK.js
Attempted import error: 'daDK' is not exported from 
'@mui/material/locale' (imported as 'daDKCore').
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance
P.S:
local build in production mode is also failed.
but error was different

```
Attempted import error: 'useGridApiContext'
 is not exported from '@mui/x-data-grid'
```

I wonder if this `useGridApiContext` is not for the community version of `mui-x-data-grid` package.
If so, how it worked in dev mode?

P.S:
after removing that `useGridApiContext`, still netlify build failed.
but local build is working.

```
https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#browsers-data-updating
Failed to compile.
./node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/locales/daDK.js
Attempted import error: 
'daDK' is not exported from '@mui/material/locale' (imported as 'daDKCore').
```